# Como reajustar a imagem para o tamanho da div

Tags: html, css

Esta imagem tem 500px x 500px e a div tem 600px x 600 px 
Como consigo tratar a imagem para ficar do mesmo tamanho da div?

```css
   #conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1; 
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div id='conteudo'> 
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Hazard_X.svg/500px-Hazard_X.svg.png">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar o seletor filho `>`, assim `#conteudo > img` e aplicar `width` e `height` com `100%;`, assim só irá afetar a imagem que for filho direto de `#conteudo`

Exemplo:

```css
#conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#conteudo > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='conteudo'> 
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Hazard_X.svg/500px-Hazard_X.svg.png">
</div>
```

Pode ocorrer da imagem ficar distorcida, então você pode optar por usar `100%` somente no height ou width, o que não vai preencher, para preencher tudo ou distorce a imagem (acaso ela seja mais retangular que o elemento "pai") ou então deve ultrapassar a largura ou altura, por exemplo veja como fica distorcido:

```css
#conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#conteudo > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='conteudo'> 
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png">
</div>
```

### Preencher e manter a proporção

Para ultrapassar o tamanho e ainda conseguir manter a proporção pode usar `min-width` e `min-heigth`, por exemplo:

```css
#conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#conteudo > img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='conteudo'> 
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png">
</div>
```

Desta maneira irá manter a proporção do tamanho da imagem em relação ao elemento "pai" sem distorcer.

### Com background-size

O CSS tem uma propriedade chamada `background-size`, do qual lhe permite ajustar o tamanho do background

#### background-size: cover

Irá ajustar até ocupar tudo

```css
#conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;

    background:#ff1 url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png) no-repeat; /*aplica a imagem*/
    background-size: cover; /*Ajusta o tamanho para "cobrir"*/
}
```

```html
<div id='conteudo'>Olá mundo</div>
```

#### background-size: contain

Irá ajustar até ocupar a largura ou altura

```css
#conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;

    background:#ff1 url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png) no-repeat; /*aplica a imagem*/
    background-size: contain; /*Ajusta o tamanho para "cobrir"*/
}
```

```html
<div id='conteudo'>Olá mundo</div>
```

Comment: o jeito que você me passou deu certinho !! teria como fazer com um background?!

Comment: @MateusAlcântara tem sim, um minuto

Comment: Desde já obrigado

Comment: @MateusAlcântara editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, mas no meu caso pelo background ainda não deu certo, quando eu clico em uma imagem e ela é aberta dentro do background, fica um espaço " sobrando "

Comment: @MateusAlcântara você viu que são dois exemplo, um com cover e outro com contain né?

Comment: Sim, reparei, testei com os dois

Comment: @MateusAlcântara manda o link do teu site pra eu ver

Comment: Ainda não está hospedado, posso te mandar de alguma outra forma?

Comment: @MateusAlcântara sabe usar o https://codepen.io/pen/?

Comment: @MateusAlcântara eu acho que você não entendeu como se usa o codepen, não é só sair colando os codigos. :(

Comment: @MateusAlcântara por isso perguntei se vc sabia usar codepen, isso mostra que não sabe. Era isso o que eu queria saber. Tem como enviar as imagens, mas é meio complicado explicar. Faz o seguinte, evnia o HTML+css+imagens via dropbox ou googledrive e me manda o link pra eu fazer download aqui nos comentários.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7BMqcQw2lmWbjV4eGZ2d2VXN2c

Comment: @MateusAlcântara mude de `background:#ff1 url(images/J2.png);` para `background:#ff1 url(../images/J2.png);` e mude de `<div class="conteudo" id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:#fff">` para `<div class="conteudo" id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">`

Answer (score 1):

```css
#conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1; 
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div id='conteudo'> 
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Hazard_X.svg/500px-Hazard_X.svg.png" width="600" height="600">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

você pode colocar o tamanho e altura direto na imagem, pelo css altura e largura 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar para ao elemento `img`, ocupar 100% da altura e do comprimento.

```
#conteudo{
width:600px;
height:600px;
float:left;
background-color:#ff1;  
display: initial;
margin: auto;
z-index: 6;
overflow: hidden;
}
img{height:100%; width:100%;}<--------------
```

Comment: existem algum jeito de deixar dentro da div conteudo, apenas?

Comment: Sim, deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: `img{` vai afetar todos elementos fora do `#conteudo`.

Comment: @MateusAlcântara como comentado pelo Guilherme se quiser que seja aplicado apenas nessa imagem vc pode fazer:
`#conteudo img{...}`, considere validar uma das respostas, clicando no icon verde abaixo as setas de avaliação, boa sorte! ;)

Comment: Titulo diz, reajustar imagem para o tamanho da div, e você usou o seletor `img {}` que vai afetar imagens dentro e fora do div, ou seja dentro do que foi perguntando funciona mas apresenta um efeito colateral que vai fazer outras imagens que não deveriam se ajustarem ao tamanho dos seus elementos "parents", o provavel seletor adequado seria `#conteudo img` ou `#conteudo > img`

Comment: @MagicHat não estou falando do código do autor, e sim do seletor que você usou. Qualquer seletor "direto" vai afetar todos elementos na página. Isso é o básico do CSS1, 2 e 3. Não estou falando de códigos específicos, estou afirmando a causa de efeitos colaterais em qualquer site, independente do código. Detalhes: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/ e https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Comment: @MagicHat cara toda vez é a mesma coisa, eu nem sei como eu me esforço ainda pra te explicar algo, é claro que causa efeito colateral, o seletor sem definir um "pai/parent" `img {}` vai afetar todas imagens de qualquer site, é efeito colateral e pronto... efeito colateral é aquele problema que pode ou não ocorrer. O titulo da pergunta esta bem claro, "Como reajustar a imagem para o tamanho da div", a tua resposta apresenta algo que vai afetar imagens dentro e fora da div, então terão imagens que se ajustarão a outros elementos, a não ser que a pagina do AP tivesse só "uma imagem"...

Comment: ...o que é raro. Eu simplesmente vou desistir de tentar te apresentar um bom caminho baseado em experiencia e deixar você lançar respostas aleatórias que podem ou não causar problemas aos APs, se você não consegue aceitar a voz da experiencia querendo te ajudar e você acredita que tudo é 100% relativo baseado em universos paralelos aonde em outro universo `img {}` e então vai ter que funcionar em todos eu simplesmente desisto. Não é a primeira vez que tento te passar alguma experiencia sobre html, css e php e vc sempre acha que não tem sentido e fica discutindo, só te dou um ultimo conselho:

Comment: Estudo o básico e depois o avançado das coisas e faça testes em diferentes ambientes (se for web aplique o css em diferentes paginas) e só então terá certeza das coisas. Se quiser aprender pelo caminho já trilhado, otimo, caso contrário eu lavo as minhas mãos. Até outra hora.;

Comment: No exemplo tem só 1 imagem,  e usando esse seletor direto, é o mesmo que dizer : "Todas as imagens terão 100% da altura da e da largura da div", é simples não precisa complicar , viu... Se por ventura ele tiver outras imagens ele poderá regular o tamanho pela div, entende..
Eu sei como funciona o comportamento do css afinal é o básico, já era para você ter percebido, que o básico eu compreendo. Agradeço sua atenção e passar outros pontos de vista... Mas é tudo suposição...@GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Mô carnaval em uma resposta correta, depois se limpa essa bagunça ai nos comentários pls...@GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Que ponto de vista, isso não é ponto de vista, é explicação do comportamento, ponto de vista é como eu vejo, isso não é como eu vejo que eu lhe expliquei, é como funciona as coisas. Olha desisto, tudo vc pensa que é uma coisa relativa e fixa ao mesmo tempo, eu não sei se é tua maneira de pensar ou qualquer coisa assim, mas não é a primeira vez que te digo, não tem nada de relatividade no comportamento básico, eu já falei sobre php html e css contigo e vc sempre fica debatendo e fazendo confusão do entendimento...

Comment: ...  Eu acho melhor desistir de explicar, cara nada contra ti, se quiser ajuda não vou negar, mas eu simplesmente não vou mais lhe apontar aonde estão as falhas, eu to começando a achar ou que vc acha que tudo é tão relativo que um img simples pode criar uma coisa gigante ou então vc acha que eu vivo de "achismo" (eu acho isso, eu acho aquilo, etc), vou apagar a conversa. Se quiser ajuda e aprender blz, mas simplesmente não me meto mais por boa vontade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vei, que tinha no seu café hoje? Tá moscando?? Se tá levantando uma questão que nem o AP levantou... Fica melhor no chat para essas coisas que podem ser de um jeito ou de outro.... Vai tomar um copo com água, bem devagar....é dá um +1 ai pela minha paciência

Comment: @MagicHat pode até ser que meu café estivesse forte, mas com certeza vc nem esta lendo com atenção minima... olha desisto essa conversa não tá levando a nada se não é lido o que foi escrito. Até outra hora.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento blz...bom descanso...É sempre bom falar com vc, vc sabe.